# Why can't I align the "Forgot Password" text to the right?

Tags: javascript, css, react-bootstrap

This is using React Bootstrap. I want to align the Forgot Password text to the right of the Password text, I've tried using several classNames like "float-right" and "justify-content-end". I can't get it to move at all.

CSS:

```
@import url(../GlobalProperties.css);


#LoginPage{
    background-color: var(--_gray);
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

#LoginForm{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#forgot-pass{
    float: right;
}
```

React code js/typescript

```
   return (
            <>
                <TopNavBar></TopNavBar>
                
                <Container fluid id="LoginPage" className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div id="LoginForm">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title className="text-center mb-4">Log in</Card.Title>
                                {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
                                <Form id="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Group className="form-group" id="email">
                                        <Form.Label>E-Mail Address</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
                                        {/* <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Email is invalid
                                        </div> */}
                                    </Form.Group>
    
                                    <Form.Group className = "form-group" id="password">
                                        <Form.Label> Password
                                            <div id="forgot-pass" className="float-right">
                                                <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
                                        {/* <div class="invalid-feedback">Password is required</div> */}
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group>
                                        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Remember me">Remember me</Form.Check>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
                                        Log in
                                    </Button>
                                </Form>
                                <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
                                    Need an account? <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
                                </div>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </>
        )
```

Comment: create a stackblitz link

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d-flex` combined with `justify-content-between` in your `Form.Label` like this:

```
<Form.Label className="d-flex justify-content-between">
    Password
    <div id="forgot-pass" >
        <a href="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
</Form.Label>
```